# How to restrict Admin from creating new users from Add new user screen in dashboard to only of one domain?

Tags: users, user-registration

I have previously added the following code in `/wp-includes/user` but it restricts registration to only front-end user. I want to put restriction on back-end user addition.

```
elseif (!preg_match('#[@.]gmail.com$#i', $user_email){
    $errors->add( 'invalid_email', __( 'ERROR: Only "gmail.com" email address allowed.' ) );
    $user_email = '';
}
```

Comment: Did you modify the core files? If yes, that's not a good idea. Please reverse this and update your question about what exactly you are looking for, so we can offer a solution.

Comment: yes i have reverted them. My question is how to restrict Admin so that he can create only one domain backend users from Add new user screen in dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into `registration_error` and check if the user's email is under your specified domain or not:

```
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'user_email_checker', 10, 3 );
function user_email_checker( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {
    if ( !preg_match('#[@.]gmail.com$#i', $user_email ) {
        $errors->add( 'invalid_email', __( 'ERROR: Only "gmail.com" email address allowed.' ) );
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

This way you don't have to deal with the core directly.

Further readings at :  [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form).